# Bad Request (404) using Spring MVC 3

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I keep getting an HTTP Bad Request however i'm not sure why. Below is my code that is producing the error:

```
$http(
            {
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8081/spring/employee-module/searchvalue',
                data : $scope.idNumber,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

Comment: Bad url or route not existing in spring maybe ?

Comment: "Bad Request" is not 404.  Without knowing what the server application expects / does we cannot tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is mal-formed.  Try this:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8081/spring/employee-module/searchvalue', {
    data: $scope.idNumber,
    headers: {
        //did you mean x-www-form-urlencoded??
        'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
}, function(error) {
    //error
});
```

Comment: If it was "mal-formed" it wouldn't send a request in the first place. `'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` is the default anyway.

Comment: OP had some extra brackets {} () etc...  That's why it was mal-formed.